# Cannot copy a database schema to another SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, compare, database-schema, migrate

I have a large database that has to be recreated onto an older SQL Server instance. The database was kept with Compatibility level setting that corresponds to the older server. I know, it doesn't guarantee full backwards compatibility, but the database schema was initially created and maintained with the older server version in mind.

Here's what I have tried:

- backup -> restore; of course it did not work because a database backup cannot be downgraded when creating it on a newer server version (oh Microsoft, why Compat level doesn't also generate compatible backups?)
- DACPAC -> for unknown reason it fails, claiming that it's missing some dependent objects (but they are present in the database)
- generate schema scripts - on newer SQL Management Studio (tried v17 and v18) it fails with 
  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoException: Cyclic dependencies found.`.  On older SQL Management Studio (2008) it doesn't fail but generates a script with objects in wrong order, so that views are being created before tables referenced in views, and, of course, execution of such a script fails
- Visual Studio Schema compare tool - fails with meaningless warning and leaves Update button disabled `Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error: An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.`

Is there a working (preferably - free) solution to this problem? How to duplicate the database schema on an empty database on another server?

Source SQL server version: 2017

Target SQL server version: 2008 R2

Database compatibility level: 2008 (100)

Comment: Theoretically yes. You have enough rep to know how to ask. What are the versions of SQL Servers involved? What is the compatibility settings chosen? (I can see that you are using SSMS 17 and 18 - helpful to know).

Comment: RE "On older SQL Management Studio it generates a script with objects in wrong order, so that views are being created before tables referenced in views" - Assuming `IF NOT EXISTS` constructs are used and statements are separated by `GO`, then you can simply run the script a few times, until all dependant objects get created. (Done that myself before)

Comment: @Alex  Added version numbers. However, while searching for the errors, I found that these error messages have plagued SQL Management Studio for years, independent of SQL server and database versions.  Thanks for the hint about "IF NOT EXISTS" though - I'll try to run with this setting enabled.  About the rep - SO seems to give too much credit, I've not deserved that :D

Comment: SSMS has a setting (Advanced->"Script for Server version") to generate scripts compatible with earlier versions. This may be helpful as well.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Thank you, yes, "Include IF EXISTS" and repeated execution helped a lot. "Script for Server version" was irrelevant because I have to use SSMS 2008, which has SQL 2008 version as the latest supported anyway (could not use a newer SSMS because of the `Cyclic` error - wondering why Microsoft doesn't fix it for years...).

Comment: Add this as answer maybe? (You will have my upvote)

Comment: Yes, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll mark it as the best one. It seems, there's no other better solution for this issue at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilising `IF NOT EXISTS` constructs and batch separators (`GO`) allows you to run your script multiple times.

On the first attempt some objects may not be created but these errors will not prevent the rest of the script from executing.

Running the script multiple times, until no more errors are returned, will create all objects.

Disclaimer: comes from personal experience.